# Problems with NuGet packages in .NET solution with two projects - binaries not being written to startup bin directory

Tags: vb.net, nuget-package

I have a legacy VB .NET website that has been written as two projects - a 'Core' project providing a class library and the startup 'UI' project, which uses the 'Core' functionality. I have installed ABCpdf and ABCpdf.ABCGecko in both projects via the NuGet package manager. However, I find that when I build the project, some of the required runtime DLLs (and other files) are only copied to the bin directory under the 'Core' project and are missing from the 'UI' bin file. In order for the application to work properly, I need to manually copy these files in.

Since I will be publishing the application to Azure, I am concerned about whether this process of manual copying. I am not sure it will be done properly on the destination environment. It also causes problems regarding backing up to GitHub, since keeping working copies means storing the binary files on the remote repository.

Is there some configurational way to get this working properly?

Comment: First off, is the reference actually needed in both projects?  If you're only using these nugets in the core, don't put them in the UI project (or vice versa).  Otherwise you can look at the _CopyLocal_ property of the references in the Solution Explorer